# Kohana Request set content-type

Tags: kohana

I am having difficulty setting the content-type header of an external Kohana3.1+ request.

```
$r = Request::factory($this->api)
    ->method(Request::PUT)
    ->body($this->to_json())
    ->headers('content-type', 'application/json');
```

The request ends up being executed by curl.  The CURLOPT_ settings for the request type (PUT) and the request body (the json) are set correctly, but the content type does not get set.

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: As stated below, this was a bug in Kohana v3.1.1 that was fixed in v3.1.2, which was released 2011/03/14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug. The question was answered here:

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/8378/set-content-type-for-external-put-requests

You can cherry pick a fix here:

http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3830

Answer (score 0):

I should not be answering questions when a zombie, have you tried fixing the capitalization? I can't remember if it makes a difference.

[headers()](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.1/develop/classes/kohana/request.php#L1264) in the source code.

<strike>You are probably looking for the [Accept header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Try this:</strike>

```
$r = Request::factory($this->api)
    ->method(Request::PUT)
    ->body($this->to_json())
    ->headers('Accept', 'application/json');
```

Comment: It was a bug. I've found a fix. Thanks for your answer.